# Add menu entry to Configure menu in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I develop an Eclipse plug-in and I need to add an entry to the Configure menu. I don't find any way to do this.

My plug-in extension look like this:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="true"
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.projectConfigure?after=org.eclipse.m2e.enableNatureAction">
     <command
           commandId="org.tatami.commands.commandConfigure"
           label="Convert to Tatami Project"
           style="push">
     </command> tooltip="Convert to Tatami Project">
  </menuContribution>


</extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="tatami.commands.ConfigureHandler"
            description="Ajouter le framework de test Tatami au Projet"
            id="org.tatami.commands.commandConfigure"
            name="Convert to Tatami Project">
      </command>
   </extension>
```

Do you find any error in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you find any error when starting ?

You could try :

```
locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.projectConfigure?after=additions">
```

Comment: Think, this is the correct location URI. You save me :)